# MRI: Why are some methods implemented as aliases, but others duplicated?

Tags: ruby, vm-implementation, language-implementation, mri, alias-method

Browsing through the MRI codebase, I find that some aliased methods are defined *as aliases*, but other times not.

For example, `TrueClass#inspect` is an alias to its `#to_s` ([source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/cdf39ed/object.c#L4539)):

```c
rb_define_alias(rb_cTrueClass, "inspect", "to_s");
```

... but `Object#is_a?` is *not* an alias for `kind_of?`, instead, they define two separate methods with the same implementing function ([source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/cdf39ed/object.c#L4439-L4440)):

```c
rb_define_method(rb_mKernel, "kind_of?", rb_obj_is_kind_of, 1);
rb_define_method(rb_mKernel, "is_a?", rb_obj_is_kind_of, 1);
```

This distinction is observable from "userspace" Ruby, too:

```rb
# Aliased methods have a different `original_name`:
true.method(:inspect).original_name # => :to_s

# "Duplicated" methods don't:
true.method(:is_a?).original_name # => :is_a?
true.method(:kind_of?).original_name # => :kind_of?
```

Is there a pattern to when aliases used, vs. when they're not? Does it make a difference?

Comment: I can't say it's the reason, but `Object#is_a?` can be overridden without overriding `Object#kind_of?`, and, of course, vice-versa, whereas overriding `TrueClass#to_s` affects `TrueClass#inspect` as well.

Comment: @CarySwoveland _"overriding `TrueClass#to_s` affects `TrueClass#inspect` as well"_ – sounds reasonable, but trying to override `TrueClass#to_s` doesn't seem to actually change the output from `inspect`

Comment: The code style could have historic reasons: the `is_a?` / `kind_of?` duplication is from 1999 whereas the `inspect` / `to_s` alias was added in 2012.

Comment: @Stefan overwriting the `to_s` method in ruby will not impact the `inspect` alias as the alias will reference the method as defined at the point of aliasing (the C implementation in this case). Similar to `class Foo; def bar; 'bar'; end; alias qux bar; def bar; 'foo';end;end` then `Foo.new.bar #=> 'foo'` but `Foo.new.qux #=> 'bar'`

Comment: You're looking at a code-base that has continuously evolved since 1995. There's going to be *weird* stuff in there.

Comment: @tadman It's hard to know what's genuinely weird, and what is intentional and has a significance that I just don't understand. Hence the question :)

Comment: It's not always easy to tell the difference.

Comment: It's always fun trying to understand whether something is intentionally or incidentally weird. An _intentionally_ weird thing should always have a comment, but that's not typically the case in practice. Failing that, something _intentionally_ weird should ideally have specific test coverage, so that a later programmer who happens upon the intentionally weird thing and decides to "clean it up" will trip over a failing test. Have you tried changing one of the `rb_define_method` calls to an `rb_define_alias` and running tests?

Answer (score 4):

**This is by no means an authoritative answer to the question**, nor does it truly answer the questions posed; however, it does provide some distinguishing characteristics between the options provided and was far too verbose to meet the format of a reasonable comment.

**Questions**

> Is there a pattern to when aliases used, vs. when they're not?

I can't say. Possibly only Matz or a part of the core team could answer this for you.

> Does it make a difference?

It could as shown here.

There is a notable difference between aliasing and defining multiple methods with the same implementation, when it comes to redefinition of the function<sup>1</sup> (or method) referenced.

**Aliasing**

```c
rb_define_alias(rb_cTrueClass, "inspect", "to_s");
```

`rb_define_alias` actually clones the function definition when creating the alias using [`rb_method_entry_clone`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/vm_method.c#L684).

Since the function is actually cloned (and not just referenced) any subsequent change to `rb_mod_to_s` (the function `to_s` refers to) or redefinition of the actual `to_s` method within Ruby code will not impact the definition of `inspect`, which will still represent the original function.

This is how `alias` and `alias_method`<sup>2</sup> in higher level ruby work as well, using essentially the same function calls as `rb_define_alias`

**Separate Method Definitions with the same implementation**

```c
rb_define_method(rb_mKernel, "kind_of?", rb_obj_is_kind_of, 1);
rb_define_method(rb_mKernel, "is_a?", rb_obj_is_kind_of, 1);
```

`rb_define_method` simply creates a method reference to the underlying function, so should the implementation of `rb_obj_is_kind_of` change, such change would impact both `kind_of?` and `is_a?` since they are directly referencing that function.

**Higher Level Example**

We can see similar behavior within Ruby:

```rb
class Foo 

   # Aliasing
  def to_s = 'Foo'
  alias inspect to_s 
  # or even this which more visibly represents the concept of cloning a method
  define_method(:other_inspect, instance_method(:to_s))

  # Separate Method Definitions with the same implementation
  def _kind_of? = true
  define_method(:is_a?) {_kind_of?}
  define_method(:kind_of?) {_kind_of?}
end 

Foo.new.to_s #=> 'Foo' 
Foo.new.inspect #=> 'Foo' 
Foo.new.other_inspect #=> 'Foo' 
Foo.new.is_a? #=> true
Foo.new.kind_of? #=> true

class Foo 
  def to_s = 'Bar'
  def _kind_of? =false
end 

Foo.new.to_s #=> 'Bar' 
Foo.new.inspect #=> 'Foo' 
Foo.new.other_inspect #=> 'Foo' 
Foo.new.is_a? #=> false 
Foo.new.kind_of? #=> false
```

Also note even though the definition of `to_s` has changed the "original name" for both `inspect` and `other_inspect` will still return `to_s`.

<sub>(1) The term function was used in this post because the question is specifically referring to the underlying C implementation. Ruby as a language does not have functions.</sub>

<sub>(2) There are distinct differences between `alias` and `alias_method` beyond the scope of this question</sub>

Comment: Hey @engineersmnky, thanks for taking the time to write in. I think this post does a good job explanation of explaining the situation, but it falls short of explaining the underlying motivation/distinction, which is really what my question is looking for. Funny enough, I do have access to some core contributors, I'll ask them to chime in :)

Comment: @Alexander I 100% agree it falls short of truly answering the questions posed, unfortunately I am not in a position to answer design decisions for ruby core. I simply thought the distinction was worth memorializing for future readers and it would have been difficult to encapsulate in a comment.

Comment: Agree, thanks for capturing that. Could you edit in a part about how aliases _don't_ update to call a new method, when their pointed-to method is overridden? That's a common misconception that's worth spelling out (e.g. as seen in the comments on my main post above)

Comment: I don't actually see much difference between an alias (`Foo#inspect`) and a duplicate method definition (`Foo#other_inspect`). Redefining `Foo#to_s` only affects `to_s`, the other two methods still refer to the original method definition of `to_s`.

Comment: @Stefan `Foo#other_inspect` is another means of aliasing (or more accurately cloning) a method. What it does is encapsulate the definition of `to_s` (in an `UnboundMethod`) at the point where `instance_method` is called. If that usage adds confusion I can certainly remove it

Comment: Isn't Ruby's `define_method` what resembles C's `rb_define_method` most closely?

Comment: @Stefan yes it is however the definition provided for `other_inspect` is pseudo `define_method new_method_name, clone(old_method_name)` which more visibly represents the way `rb_alias` functions. [Here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/vm_method.c#L2316)